# RandomizedSearchCV for XGboost, imbalanced dataset and optimum iterations count (n_iter)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, xgboost

I am working on a imbalanced (9:1) binary classification problem and would like to use Xgboost & RandomizedSearchCV.

As shown in code there are  472,50,000 (5*7*5*5*5*5*6*4*9*10) combinations of hyperparameters. With 10-fold CV the above number becomes 472,500,000 (4.725 million)

Its usually suggested for randomizedsearchcv 5-10% of total combinations should be taken. 5-10% of 4.725 million would be a very high number.

So my question is what **would be a good 'n_iter' value** to take so that good results are obtained within reasonable time/computational efficiency?

Note on a potential query:some paramneters like 'scale_pos_weight', 'max_delta_step' are not usually tuned but I have included them as my data is imbalanced.

Thanks!

```
param_dist= {
              "max_depth": [2,3,4,5,6],
              "learning_rate":[0.01,0.02,0.03,0.05,0.1,0.3,0.5],
    "min_child_weight":[1,2,3,4,5],
              "subsample":[i/10.0 for i in range(6,10)],
 "colsample_bytree":[i/10.0 for i in range(6,10)],
               "reg_alpha":[1e-5, 1e-2, 0.1, 1, 100],
              "gamma":[i/10.0 for i in range(0,5)],
    "n_estimators":[100,500,700,1000],
    'scale_pos_weight':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],
    'max_delta_step': range(1,10,1)

              }
```

Comment: Do you have `early_stopping_rounds` set for `xgboost` training? Your question depends on what time does it take for training the model on an average and how much is a reasonable amount for you.

Comment: To add, ideally you dont have to tune `scale_pos_weight`. You have to set it at `9`.

Comment: Thanks Nihal- for pointing out scale_pos_weight, yes it should simple be 9.

Comment: @NihalSangeeth Early stopping I have not set  but yes I will do that. Model training time is a constraint but not a big one, since I want as high recall and precision as possible I can be patient working out this model.

What you suggest I should do for n_iter optimum value given I am preferring right classification over time and also suggest what should n_iter when time is a constraint. Is there a way to achieve reasonably good n_iter number in a situation of limited time. Your help would be deeply appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: This is a randomized search. So there is no guarantee that the optimal parameters are found even if you take 90% of combinations. There is also a chance that the optimal parameters might be in 10 combinations you pick. I suggest read about the parameters and try fixing some of those depending on your dataset and features.

Comment: Also parameters like learning rate might have no dependency on other parameters. You can leave them out and tune them seperately.

Comment: scale_pos_weight is also tuned parameter with possible entries [0, sqrt(class_ratio), class_ratio]. Square root sometimes improves so its worth to try.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the comments as answer.

Your question depends on what time does it take for training the model on an average and how much is a reasonable amount for you.

This is a randomized search. So there is no guarantee that the optimal parameters are found even if you take 90% of combinations. There is also a chance that the optimal parameters might be in 10 combinations you pick. I suggest read about the parameters and try fixing some of those depending on your dataset and features.

First of all you dont have to tune scale_pos_weight. You have to fix it at 9 since  you have a 9:1 imbalanced dataset.

Also parameters like learning rate might have no dependency on other parameters. You can leave them out and tune them seperately.

Comment: `scale_pos_weight` can be also tuned such as with class_ratios, square root of class_ratios and 1. Fixing that parameter does not work always well.